# If $f$ is continuous then $g(x) = f(a x + b)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $g(x) = f(a x + b)$ is continuous.

$f$ is continuous at $a c + b$, so for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta' > 0$ such that $|x - (c + b)| < \delta'$ implies $|f(x) - f(a c + b)| < \epsilon$.

Now, to prove that $g$ is continuous let $\epsilon > 0$, we use $\delta = \frac{\delta'}{|a|}$, so:

$|x - c| < \delta = \frac{\delta'}{|a|}$

$|a| |x - c| < \delta'$

$|(a x + b) - (a c + b)| < \delta'$

So:

$|g(x) - g(c)| = |f(a x + b) - f(a c + b)| < \epsilon$

Is this correct?

Comment: $a$ might be zero, so it is better to write $\delta = \delta'/(|a|+1)$.

Comment: It is better without that "+1" , even when $a$ might be 0. OP should handle $a=0$ Case easily (function is Constant!) , then move on to non-zero Case , @Riemann

Comment: @Prem It is matter of choice, I think. It is of course okay to deal with the case $a = 0$ separately, but it makes the proof more lengthier. Many books on analysis prefers using $+1$.